# Can Taq polymerase be used instead of polymerase Vent exo (-)?

Tags: molecular-biology, pcr

Instead of using  polymerase Vent  exo (-), can I go with the usual *Taq* polymerase?

Do the PCR conditions change (the temperature and master mix concentrations ) in the these two conditions? Do the primers (sequence and concentrations) change if we use vent exo instead of *Taq* polymerase and vice versa? If the primers are designed specifically for Vent exo (-) how can I modify the PCR conditions so that I can use the same primers (meant for vent exo) using *Taq* polymerase?

Comment: Can you describe what you need the PCR for, what your requirements on accuracy and other factors are?

Comment: SNP detection, using ARMS PCR

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done ARMS PCR myself, so my answer is based on theory and there might be other practical factors I overlooked.

The characteristic feature of the [Vent exo(-) polymerase](http://www.neb.com/nebecomm/products/productm0257.asp) is the lack of exonuclease activity compared to the regular Vent polymerase. ARMS uses the fact that a mismatch at the 3' position prevents primer extension. For this to work it is important to use a polymerase without exonuclease activity, as such a polymerase could "repair" the mismatch and the whole method would not work. [Taq polymerase](http://www.neb.com/nebecomm/products/productm0273.asp) also doesn't have any exonuclease activity, so in theory you should be able to use it for this experiment.

The primers don't have to be changed for different polymerases, the polymerase buffer though is different and I wouldn't recommend using the wrong one.